# which function with magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I don't understand why the combination of magrittr and the which function doesn't work !!

```
> x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
> x %>% which(. == TRUE)
[1] 1 2 3 5
> x %>% which(. == FALSE)
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

The last one is clearly wrong.
however this works:

```
> x %>% (function(s){which(s==TRUE)})
[1] 1 2 3 5
> x %>% (function(s){which(s==FALSE)})
[1] 4
```

also this works:

```
> x %>% which
[1] 1 2 3 5
> (!x) %>% which
[1] 4
>
```

I guess '.' notation won't work with the equivalent sign '=='

Any idea ?
Appreciated in advance

Comment: `which(x==FALSE)` returns the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic concept of pipe :**

The left-hand side of pipe is the first argument to the function in right hand side.

So when you do :

```
c(1, 2, 3) %>% sum
#[1] 6
```

it means you are doing :

```
sum(c(1, 2, 3))
#[1] 6
```

---

Similarly, when you do :

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
x %>% which(. == TRUE)
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

It means you are doing

```
which(x, x == TRUE)
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

and

```
x %>% which(. == FALSE)
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

is same as

```
which(x, x == FALSE)
#[1] 1 2 3 5
```

So when using pipes `x == TRUE`  and `x == FALSE` are treated as second argument to `which` which is `arr.ind`.

You can stop this behavior of pipe which is LHS of pipe as first argument to function in RHS by using `{}`. In which case you'll get expected output.

```
x %>% {which(. == TRUE)}
#[1] 1 2 3 5

x %>% {which(. == FALSE)}
#[1] 4
```

Also note that you don't really need to compare logical values with `==`.

```
x %>% which
```

and

```
x %>% `!` %>% which
```

works the same way.

Comment: Thanks -- I understand the '.' notation better now

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why

```
x %>% which(. == FALSE)
```

doesn't work

I think magrittr function somehow disregards all the rest of the argument

```
> x %>% which(. <= 3 + 3)
[1] 1 2 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised the answer to this question, which needs a logical input and only checks if it is true
so I have to do change x to a logical value first

```
> (x == TRUE) %>% which()
[1] 1 2 3 5
> (x == FALSE) %>% which()
[1] 4
```

This also works

```
> x %>% equals(., TRUE) %>% which()
[1] 1 2 3 5
> x %>% equals(., FALSE) %>% which()
[1] 4
```

Comment: Why on earth will you compare a logica to another logical?  Why would you say `x==TRUE`? this is just `x` eg. `y <- x==TRUE` check y and x, they are exactly the same. Hence redundant

Answer (score 0):

My attempt for the ugliest pipeline :

```
x %>% `==`(FALSE) %>% which()
```